# Make shell script change script location

Tags: bash, shell

I have currently put together a script to move files from one directory to another.

This has gone ok however I was wondering if there was a way via a shell script to get it to run from anywhere on the server e.g I give the script for someone to use on their server and they can put the script anywhere and it will run.

I know a workaround is to put the script in /usr/local/bin or usr/bin and you can run it from anywhere but that is not what I want.

Is there a way that my script will auto run from usr/local/bin regardless of if it is in /scripts for instance?

Please see my script below:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
mkdir -p /var/Alitest
echo "This is a test that I have created. This is to
 see if the output is successful I normally do this manually but a script is required" > /var/Alitest/action.txt
sed -i 's/This is a test that I have created/The test has been successful/g' /var/Alitest/action.txt
chmod 744 /var/Alitest/action.txt
chown root:root Alitest/action.txt
mv /var/Alitest/action.txt /script/action.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Also in my log output for the script the following error is shown:

```
sed: 1: "/var/Alitest/action.txt": invalid command code A
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *to run **from** /usr/local/bin*?

Comment: user1934428 basically the script will run on automation what I would like it for my script to be executable from any directory on the server. Is there a string that could be added to the above script to achieve this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. If a program is somewhere in a file system, you can execute it, as long as you have permission to access it. I personally would not put my own stuff into /usr/local/bin. This is not a technical reason, but one of organization; this should be reserved for tools which belong to the OS distribution. Maybe /opt/bin would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a soft link in /usr/local/bin for your script. Then it will be in everyone's path to be executed.

e.g. ln -s /script/yourscript.sh /usr/local/bin/yourscript.sh

Comment: Thank you for this. Would it be possible to insert this into the script somehow. I understand that this can be done via the command line however I wanted the script to action this. Would it be a case of putting in a primary script before this one in order for this to work or can this be done by one script?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the matter further I have decided the the best way to action this is to add the folder destination e.g /scripts to my path.

This can be done by vimming into the .bashrc file on the server and adding the below line:

export PATH=/dir_name:$PATH

remember to refresh the profile in order for the changes to take effect.

You can check if this has been successful by running the below command:

echo $PATH

There is no way to get your script to do this however this would be better then a softlink as if you add it to $PATH then you do not have to go through the task of adding softlinks each time.

Thank you all for your help.

Kind Regards
Ali